How increasing pressure and temperature by adding CO2 to Mars atmosphere, would solve the other problems to make it suitable for humans?
Many times it's seen articles or even papers in internet talking about making Mars suitable for humans and plants by adding CO2 which would increase temperature and pressure. Elon Musk suggested the process could be speed up by nuking the poles.
What I don't understand is how they expect to solve other problems. Even if you assume that you could turn CO2 to O2 fast by adding a lot of plants or whatever, it took 2 billions years since the appearance of organisms who could generate oxygen via photosynthesis for an ozone layer to be formed on Earth. Can you speed up this process with plants or something? Can an ozone layer be formed at all in Mars?
And most importantly,

The lack of a strong magnetic field also allowed cosmic rays to hit
the atmosphere directly, leading to any gas molecules being
effectively ‘sand blasted’ away. As a result, cosmic rays would make
life on Mars just as hostile as life on the Moon.

The effects of magnetic fields
How increasing pressure and temperature by adding CO2 to Mars atmosphere, would solve the other problems to make it suitable for humans?

Related: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/14352/place-a-satellite-at-sun-mars-l1-to-shield-mars-from-sun-radiation

The lack of a magnetic field does lead to atmospheric erosion, but that's a very slow process compared to a human lifespan (or even a civilization), so in the short term it's not really a problem. It would take millions of years to go from something like Earth's atmosphere to something like Mars.
A layer of CO2 gets you heat and pressure, which alleviate two of the biggest problems of living on Mars. You still couldn't walk outside without an oxygen tank, but you could ditch the bulky space suit in favor of a simple positive-pressure mask, and probably some sort of robe or other protective covering to help deal with the high UV levels. Your buildings still need to be sealed, but they can be sealed like an airliner or a refrigerator, rather than like a space capsule.
As far as solar radiation is concerned, yes, the lack of ozone is going to make it tough on the UV level, but just having a few miles of gas above your head will block a lot of the beyond-ultraviolet radiation (x-rays, gamma rays, cosmic rays). Colonists living and working on the surface might have to worry about skin cancer, but at least they aren't risking radiation poisoning.
Getting the atmosphere converted from locally-sourced CO2 to something we can breathe is an extremely long-term project that's really more science fiction than solid plans right now, and probably wouldn't even work. Converting that much CO2 would likely require oceans full of cyanobacteria and maybe autonomous atmosphere factories that can crack CO2 (to fill bins with useful carbon while exhaling oxygen). And then you still have the problem of partial pressures -- 20% oxygen with 80% CO2 is poison, but 98% oxygen is also poison in the long term (see "oxygen toxicity"). You need the bulk of the atmosphere to be something that's basically nonreactive to earth biology, like nitrogen or helium, in order for mammal life to exist on the surface without equipment. That's the real trick, because there doesn't seem to be a local source for it, and importing an entire planet's worth of atmosphere is an incredibly huge task.

I'll also add that the atmosphere being mostly CO2 is actually sort of helpful as compared to other gasses, because mammals are very sensitive to dangerously elevated CO2 levels in a way that they aren't to other gasses. If your dome is leaking and filling with CO2, you'll start to cough and gasp immediately, where if you have nitrogen or neon replacing oxygen around you, you won't notice a thing until you pass out.

DarthPseudonym - I wonder if it eventually turns out to be easier to increase the amount (and thus pressure) of CO2 in the atmosphere than doing the same with oxygen. I'm not sure if that's possible though. But while on the surface that would seem to not be of any help, it would allow wearing just an oxygen mask when outdoors instead of a pressure suit or pressure garment. And it would slow down leaks from enclosed facilities or vehicles. And as you mentioned a leak would be more quickly noticed because of the increased level of CO2 being breathed.

@StevePemberton The whole concept is pretty much based on the fact that there's a lot of local CO2 on Mars already, we just need to melt and release it -- at least, as I understand it.

DarthPseudonym - that's what I was assuming, but I wasn't sure. I'm not really up on what all of the terraforming proposals are, I thought the next step was to try and generate oxygen through plants or other methods. And I assumed (perhaps wrongly) that not doing so would be considered a failure in terms of permanent colonization, or at best a partial success. But doing some quick reading just now, I guess creating a breathable atmosphere is not considered likely, and they just want to get a higher pressure CO2 atmosphere. I hadn't realized until now the advantages of that just by itself.

Yeah. The fact that there's not much nitrogen (or some other neutral gas) on Mars pretty much puts the kibosh on any sort of breathable atmosphere.

Kurzgesagt mentioned in their terraforming Mars video that Nitrogen can be shipped from Titan to Mars. Even though they didn’t really cover the how part, others have. One interesting proposal I saw was to have an orbital ring which dips one end in the atmosphere and scoops out the gases. Those are shot off from the upper end of the ring.

I don't know if I've seen the specific proposal you're talking about, but my experience with such proposals is that they tend to sort of hand-wave the problematically large energy cost of hurling gas and water across the solar system, as well the fact that the energy doesn't just disappear when the package arrives on the far end, not to mention where you're going to get containers for moving vast amounts of gas around.
